# How to set data-filter-placeholder/equivalent with jquery mobile 1.4+

Tags: jquery-mobile, input, jquery-mobile-listview

I cannot find anything really about this: 
I want to pre- populate the filter- field in jqm 1.4 on a listview. One used to do that via data-filter-placeholder, which is depreceated. What am I supposed to use then?

```
<form class="ui-filterable"><input id="filterBasic-input" data-type="search"></form>
    <ul data-role="listview" class="ui-listview-outer" data-filter="true" data-input="#filterBasic-input">
....
....
```

with the above example I can filter fine, but where do I pre-populate the filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are defining your own `<input>` for the filterable object, just define a placeholder right on the input:

```
<form class="ui-filterable">
    <input id="filterBasic-input" data-type="search" placeholder="find cars" />
</form>
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-input="#filterBasic-input">
    <li>Acura</li>
    <li>Audi</li>
    <li>BMW</li>
    <li>Cadillac</li>
    <li>Ferrari</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's it - easy as pie :) ...thank you! Have I missed that on the jQM page or should it be added there?!

Comment: Well, applying a placeholder to an input is just HTML, not really jQM, but it is covered in the textinput widget: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/textinput/#Placeholder